# Why does the library throw an exception? Fatal error. System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException

Tags: c#, c, mingw

I am using this library in my project: https://github.com/chudleigh/bloom.filter
My project is in C# and I'm using this library through wrapper: https://pastebin.com/iaWtKZaG (wrapper code)
For most users everything works fine, but for some this library throws an exception.
I asked several users to send me errors and I noticed that they differed slightly:

```
Fatal error. System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.
Repeat 2 times:
   at BloomLib.BloomFilter._check(IntPtr, Byte[], Int32)
   at BloomLib.BloomFilter.Check(Byte[])

Fatal error. System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.
Repeat 2 times:
   at BloomLib.BloomFilter._create(UInt64, Double)
   at BloomLib.BloomFilter..ctor(UInt64, Double)
```

How can this be fixed?

Running with administrator rights did nothing

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: No, I can’t reproduce the problem, I have about ~300 active users of the program, and only 5 reported the problem